# Adding a column that counts the number of occurrences of L2 values in column 'L1'

Tags: python, pandas

How do you add a column to a dataframe that counts the number of occurrences of L2 values in column 'L1' as follows:

```
input_table = pd.DataFrame({'L1':['A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C'], 'L2':['B', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'E']})

output_table = pd.DataFrame({'L1':['A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C'], 'L2':['B', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'E'], 'count L2 in L1':[1, 2, 2, 0, 0]})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `value_counts` and `transform`:

```
vc = input_table['L1'].value_counts()
input_table['count L2 in L1'] = input_table['L2'].transform(lambda x: vc.get(x, 0))
```

Output:

```
>>> input_table
  L1 L2  count L2 in L1
0  A  B               1
1  A  C               2
2  B  C               2
3  C  D               0
4  C  E               0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the groupby function from pandas module to count the occurrences of L2 in L1, and then merge the resulting data back to the original data frame based on L2.

```
    output_table = pd.merge(
        input_table,
        input_table.groupby(by='L1').count().reset_index().
            rename(columns={'L1':'L2',"L2":'count L2 in L1'}),
            how='left',on='L2').fillna(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a combination of `isin` and `groupby`:

```py
input_table['count L2 in L1'] = (input_table
                                 .L2
                                 .isin(input_table.L1)
                                 .groupby(input_table.L2)
                                 .transform('sum')
                               )

input_table

  L1 L2  count L2 in L1
0  A  B               1
1  A  C               2
2  B  C               2
3  C  D               0
4  C  E               0
```